# SignalR connection doesn't work

Tags: c#, websocket, signalr

I can't establish connection from client side to signalR host (ASP.NET MVC application).

```
 var hub = $.connection.feed;
            $.connection.hub
                .start()
                .done(function(){
                    hub.server.subscribeToFeedPosts('@group.Id.ToString()');
                });
```

It doesn't get into .done() trigger at all.

I'm using the newest version of jquery.signalR.js library (2.1.1) and quite old version of jquery.js (1.8.3). I have to use only this version of jQuery right now.

Comment: Are you including `<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="signalr/hubs"></script>`?

Comment: @Izzy, yes, of course, I have all the SignalR necessary stuff

Comment: I've tried to use the newest version of jquery.js (1.11.1) and it works fine.

Comment: does it get to `.fail()` then? What does the log say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try older version of jquery.signalR.js, it should work with 2.0.2